# Why are React onclick events are not firing when I wrap with a Vue application? (Without Other Libs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have the following react...

```
const RootTemplate = () => {
    return (
        <div id="vue-app">
            ...
            <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={this.toggle}>
                ...
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    );
};
...
render(){
    return RootTemplate.call(this);
}
```

The onclick works and no problems. Now I try to wrap the entire thing in Vue by adding this...

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.appWrapper = new App();
    this.appWrapper.app.$mount("#vue-app");
}

// Vue App
export class App{
    constructor(){
        Vue.component("test", Test);
        this.app = new Vue();
    }
}
```

The Vue and the React tags are now rendering properly, however, when I try to click on the button the `toggle` function is no longer being called.

How do I get both to live in harmony?

**Update**

I cannot use Vuera due to the controlled repo I can grab from...

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: vuera@latest
```

So this is not an option. Also we don't use Babel and that seems required for it. I would ultimately like to do this without 3rd party libs.

Even more so then how to do it I would like to know why it is not working now.

Comment: See if this can help you https://github.com/akxcv/vuera

Comment: seems to require babel, we are using webpack. I also remember reviewing that previously and had issues. Finally I work in an environment that is controlled and that dependency is not part of my repo. I will add this to the post to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get your question but have you tried using Vue's click command instead?

```
The @click event
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, probably should be a comment until confirmed. I can try that format but again it was working before being wrapped.

Comment: I couldn't create a comment because I was told I didn't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I think It was working because it interfaced directly with React, but this time around you are trying to plug Vue into it. So most likely you have to follow Vue's principle.

Comment: Sorry been busy I will give you a check as soon as I can get back to the state I can test in. Sounds logical to me and Welcome!